Cannot run Flutter iOS app (No such module 'Flutter')
I’m encountering the following error in my AppDelegate.swift file when trying to run my iOS Flutter app:
No such module 'Flutter'

and this is what I get in the debug console
Launching lib/main_dev.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `app_links` from `.symlinks/plugins/app_links/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `connectivity_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/darwin`
    -> Fetching podspec for `device_info_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info_plus/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
    firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
    firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_native_splash` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_native_splash/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `onesignal_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/onesignal_flutter/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `package_info_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/package_info_plus/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/darwin`
    -> Fetching podspec for `permission_handler_apple` from `.symlinks/plugins/permission_handler_apple/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `share_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/share_plus/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_foundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_foundation/darwin`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sqflite_darwin` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite_darwin/darwin`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `video_player_avfoundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/video_player_avfoundation/darwin`
    -> Fetching podspec for `webview_flutter_wkwebview` from `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/darwin`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_f_3.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/f/3/OneSignalXCFramework/5.3.0-beta-01/OneSignalXCFramework.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_2_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.16.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_9_f.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/11.3.0/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/11.2.0/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_b_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/11.3.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_7_f.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/7/f/FirebaseCoreExtension/11.3.0/FirebaseCoreExtension.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_1_8.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/1/8/FirebaseFirestoreInternal/11.3.0/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_b_c_7.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/b/c/7/FirebaseSharedSwift/11.3.0/FirebaseSharedSwift.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/1/8/FirebaseFirestoreInternal/11.2.0/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_e_9_8.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/9/8/FirebaseAppCheckInterop/11.3.0/FirebaseAppCheckInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_8_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240722.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.1/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.1/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.1/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.1/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.1/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.1/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.1/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.1/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20240116.2/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_9_1_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.67.0-pre1/gRPC-Core.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

    ――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

    ### Command

    ```
    /usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose
    ```

    ### Report

    * What did you do?

    * What did you expect to happen?

    * What happened instead?

    ### Stack

    ```
       CocoaPods : 1.15.2
            Ruby : ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin22]
        RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
            Host : macOS 13.7 (22H123)
           Xcode : 15.2 (15C500b)
             Git : git version 2.23.0
    Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
    Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
    ```

    ### Plugins

    ```
    cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
    cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
    cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
    cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
    cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
    cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
    ```

    ### Podfile

    ```ruby
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    platform :ios, '13.0'

    # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
    ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

    project 'Runner', {
      'Debug' => :debug,
      'Profile' => :release,
      'Release' => :release,
    }

    def flutter_root
      generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
      unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
        raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
      end

      File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
        matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
        return matches[1].strip if matches
      end
      raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
    end

    require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

    flutter_ios_podfile_setup

    target 'Runner' do
      use_frameworks!
      use_modular_headers!

      # pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.18.0'
      flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    end

    target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
      use_frameworks!
      pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
    end

    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

        # Start of the permission_handler configuration
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
          '$(inherited)',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
          'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
          'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
        ]
      end
      # End of the permission_handler configuration
      end
    end
    ```

    ### Error

    ```
    JSON::ParserError - Failed to parse JSON at file: '/Users/alimazen/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.67.0-pre1/gRPC-Core.podspec.json'.

    416: unexpected token at '"src/core/ext/upb-gen/envoy/'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:66:in `rescue in from_json'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:759:in `from_string'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:733:in `from_file'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:188:in `specification'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:58:in `block in specification_name'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `specification_name'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:216:in `search'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in `create_set_from_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in `specifications_for_dependency'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in `block in sort_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in `sort_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:744:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:727:in `activate_new_spec'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    ```

    ――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

    [!] Oh no, an error occurred.

    Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=Failed+to+parse+JSON+at+file%3A+%27%2FUsers%2Falimazen%2F.cocoapods%2Frepos%2Ftrunk%2FSpecs%2F9%2F1%2F0%2FgRPC-Core%2F1.67.0-pre1%2FgRPC-Core.podspec.json%27.%0A%0A416%3A+unexpected+token+at+%27%22src%2Fcore%2Fext%2Fupb-gen%2Fenvoy%2F%27&type=Issues

    If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

    Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

    Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

    Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
    Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
    https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

Exited (1).


This is my Podfile
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    # Start of the permission_handler configuration
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
      ]
    end
    # End of the permission_handler configuration
  end
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
end

and this is my AppDelegate.swift file
import UIKit
import Flutter
//import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseDynamicLinks

@main
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    DynamicLinks.performDiagnostics(completion: nil)

//    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

I tried to clean the project, remove pods, podfile.lock but all did not work.
i don't think this is relevant but I have flavors set up (main_dev, main_prod).
I tried to run another ios app and it worked. for this app it does not. so does anyone know how to solve this issue? i spent days trying to solve it.

Check you previous packages version updates. Firebase? Or even ios min version ? Try roll out to the versions when all was working

just ignore it and run your project . it will run .

I tried to run it with the old version, but I could not since the Flutter version I used at that time is different. I tried to update the packages, but I got this issue, so now I am stuck

Follow this step:

First Delete ==> .symlinks, pods, Podfile.lock
Flutter clean
Flutter pub get
pod install


it does not work
